# htaccess issue with directory when removing extension

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, file-extension

I use htaccess to remove .php extension from URL. The problem comes up when there's a file and a directory with the same name. By removing .php extension the server thinks I'm trying to access a directory a denies the access.

EXAMPLE
**www.europe.com/italy.php** turns into **www.europe.com/italy** but as I have a folder named italy, the servers denies the access saying "Forbidden, You don't have permission to access /italy/ on this server"

Here's my HTACCESS

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On


## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

**UPDATE:** Final code working like a charm!

```
DirectorySlash Off

IndexOptions FancyIndexing
Options All
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^/]+/)*[^.]+\.php
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^.]+)\.php$ http://www.yoursite.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^/.]+)$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: So the URL entered (or linked to) and shown in the browser's address bar is `www.europe.com/italy.php` and you are trying to map it silently to `www.europe.com/italy`? Why, it should be the other way around? Is there a resource (script) that handles the request at `www.europe.com/italy`? Access to folder `/italy` is blocked somewhere?

Comment: On browser (with the htaccess configuration I posted) www.europe.com/italy The problem is that any link pointing to that page is interpreted as if it were pointing to the folder so i get www.europe.com/italy/ Forbidden bla bla... THANKS!!

Comment: Thanks for your help @faa ! After 10 hours I could came up with the solution! I edited the original post to expose my final code.