# Folder name is the same as a file name

Tags: html, directory, root, directory-structure

In my directory I have a file called `portfolio.php`.
The navigation menu, there is a link to the portfolio file, and the href links to `portfolio.php`.

I am trying to create a folder called portfolio, and inside that folder I will add projects, i.e `project.php`,`project1.php`,`project2.php` and so on.

So the `projects` will be linked from the `portfolio` page, and the url will appear as follows for example: `portfolio.php/proejct.php`

The problem is, when I created the folder portfolio, and try to visit it, it shows the `Index of /portfolio`....

How can I fix this? I tried to place the portfolio.php page within it, but no hope. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: In the same directory as what? I'm assuming your index.php/html file.

Comment: Because I have a folder called portfolio, and a file called portfolio.php and a .htaccess that removes the php extension, do you think that is why I goes to the folder and not the file?

Comment: This isn't my area of expertise but I would give this a look. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14908303/htaccess-issue-with-directory-when-removing-extension.

Answer (score 0):

Just name your default page "index".
I work with Apache 2 and this would work.